# I get an 'index out of range' exception when pressing the browser's back button. Setting breakpoints isn't doing anything

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a particular page in my project that's giving me a major headache.

When I navigate to the page directly, or via a link.. everything works fine.  If I click a link on that page, and then hit the back button, I get a `IndexOutOfRangeException` in my custom `LoadInitialData` method at line 391 (called from Page_Load).  *Line 391 is a comment*.  If I add a bunch of extra lines to offset line 391, it doesn't change.  It always says the error is on line 391.  If I set a breakpoint on the `LoadInitialData` method, it doesn't doesn't even catch it when I hit the back button, the error just appears again.  Page_Load doesn't even fire when I hit the back button.. I don't know how I'm supposed to debug this.

I have tried rebuilding the project, tried enabling viewstate, tried disabling caching for that page, I've commented out every line I could near line 391.. I can't find where this error is occuring.

I've run into issues before where hitting the back button causes strange problems.. but this is the weirdest I've seen.

I found this page that seemed to describe a similar problem, but their solution didn't help. 
http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_debugging/debugging/article.php/c12891/Getting-Rid-of-the-Back-Button-Problem.htm

Anyone have a clue what I could do here?

Comment: Just to help debugging, go to debug->exceptions and check 'thrown' on 'Common Language Runtime Exceptions' and then see if you are able to get the IDE to break at the error. Hopefully it will break and you will be able to see what is actually throwing the exception.